# How to remove unconfirmed, non-existent transaction from QT wallet

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

I transferred 10 btc from my Coinbase acct to my wallet.  The transaction appears twice in my wallet, one went right through and confirmed within minutes, the other has 0 confirmations (after 2 weeks), and the transaction ID does not show up on blockchain.  So I got my bitcoins, but now I have this "phantom" unconfirmed transaction in my wallet.  How do I get rid if it?

Answer (score 6):

The command line option is -zapwallettxes

This will clear unconfirmed transactions from your wallet.

See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

Answer (score -1):

Try doing a rescan. start the client with -rescan

That parameter will tell the software to scan the block chain for missing wallet transactions.

Comment: However, this will not help to get rid of transactions that are already there.